# Decouple controller and view in ExtJs

Tags: architecture, extjs, extjs4, mvp

I'm studying ExtJs and trying to find the best way to organize my future project.
I started with ExtJs MVC tutorial http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/application_architecture

There is something I don't like in this architecture:
Controller "knows" about views widgets and adds events listeners this way

```
this.control({
            'viewport > userlist':{
                itemdblclick:this.editUser
            },
            'useredit button[action=save]':{
                click:this.updateUser
            }
        });
```

We are starting a large project with 500+ forms.
I beleive in such a large projects this approach is gonna create a great mess.
Is there any way to decouple controller and view?

For example, in GWT they use MVP pattern where Presenter doesn't know about view's internals
and interacts with view through "Display" interface.
I know, that Javascript doesn't have interfaces, but may be there is some way to emulate them in Extjs.

I would like my controller to be something like this:

```
editButton = viewInterface.getEditButton();
editButton.on('click', function(btn, e, eOpts) {
    eventBus.fireEvent(editUserEvent);
});
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely possible. Create a method getEditButton in your view and return whatever you want. That's not a problem.

My 2c however for decoupling view and controller. I'm also currently working on rather big project. Probably not that as big as yours, but we will have around 100+ views/controllers.

I try to architect this project using two main rules of thumb:

1. If I have some common logic whether it's in view or in controller - I create base class and move this logic there. So later on - I just extend it so child view/controllers get same functionality.
2. I leave code that's not related to the business logic of applications inside view classes - for example if I have a grid and need to add special code to select all records in the grid, or to display number of records and number of selected records in a grid inside the status bar - this code goes to view class. So controller has no idea about these 'simple' tasks and only focuses on business logic of the application.

Comment: Thank you. Can you say anything about event bus? Are there any implementations in ExtJs4 ?

Comment: I would like to second this approach. Let the controller know as little about the view as possible, and let the view generate high-level events like fireEvent.editUser(user) and let the controller(s) listen to this event.

Answer (score 1):

Having logic in the view really defeats the purpose of the MVP pattern. I recommend checking out [deftjs](https://github.com/deftjs/DeftJS) since it makes the component queries cleaner. Since most user actions are on controls such as a button I give them an action and look for that unique action, such as login.

```
 control: {
    submitButton: {
        selector: 'button[action=login]',
        listeners: {'click': 'login'}
    }
 }
```

The problem with the above is it does still tie the controller to the view component, the button, since it references its type. You could replace this by id but I am not a fan of that either. I believe the best way to get this functionality is to contribute to deftjs to have a more generic event model, which they probably have on the roadmap since they are basing it off of projects such as RobotLegs. If no one contributes this functionality soon I will probably take a stab at it.

Last but not least if you find you need to add logic to a component its probably best to extend that component and test it separate from your views.

Comment: Thanks. Why do we have to put any logic in the view? I prefer to put it in controller(presenter). And I really don't like "control" statement, because it's global. I prefer to do it this way: this.editView.getSaveButton().on('click', this.updateVehicle, this);

Comment: This is why I suggested deftJS it changes how the control statement works. It is local and much less ugly. In my example above there would be no code in the view, it would be in the presenter.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather have the views fire meaningfull events like 'edit' using fireEvent.

Controller will be aware of the view and can monitor 'edit' event on the view.

**View:**

```
this.on(this.btnEdit, 'click', function(){ this.fireEvent('edit');},this);
```

**Controller:**

```
this.mon(this.viewInstance, 'edit', this.doEdit, this);
```

This way controller dose not know about views internals.